# Select column from another table based on Id using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, razor-pages

i have the following classes :

```
public class Blog {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public String Name {get; set;}
    ...
    ...
    public int CatId {get;set;}
}

public class BlogCategory{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Blogs {get; set;}
}
```

now i have view model in my razor page :

```
public BlogViewModel{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ..
    ..
    public string CategoryName {get; set;}
}
```

i'm trying to select the blog and to contain it's category name:
my Query :

```
Blogs = await _context.Blogs
    .Select(b => new BlogViewModel()
    {
        Id = b.Id,
        Name = b.Name,        
        //CategoryName = 
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

how i can select the Category name from BlogCategory table based on the CatId i have ?

one way is to add

```
public virtual Category BlogCat {get; set;}
```

to the Blog class, then to use Include but i don't want to use this method as i only want the Category Name not the full object.

any help please ?

**The Solution:**

```
Blogs = await _context.Blogs
        .Select(b => new BlogViewModel()
        {
            Id = b.Id,
            Name = b.Name,        
            CategoryName = _context.BlogCategory
                        .Where(c => c.Id == b.CatId)
                        .Select(c => c.Name)
                        .SingleOrDefault()
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: do you have a navigation property with BlogCategory and Blog?

Comment: do you mean the CatId ? i have 
public virtual Blogs {get; set;} in the BlogCategory

Comment: yes but you don't physically tell EF that CatId is a foreign key from what you posted

Comment: So if you only need a category name can you duplicate this property and have it in Blog class as well? Another option would be to have a sql join and get a custom object which would include category name.

Comment: @Ramūnas , i have the id, why to have the name ? it's not good

Comment: Depends on the situation, by the way, why you don't want to load full Blog object?

Comment: @Ramūnas , it contains a lot of data that i don't need it in this page, maybe i need some of them in another page, so in this page i care only on some values

Answer (score 1):

```
    var blogModels = ( from b in _context.Blogs 
     join c in _context.BlogCategories 
     on b.CatId equals c.Id
     select new BlogViewModel()
      {
       Id = b.Id,
       Name = b.Name,        
       CategoryName = c.Name
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to t avoid using join style, actually i solved it and i posted the solution above.

Answer (score 1):

**The Solution:**

```
Blogs = await _context.Blogs
        .Select(b => new BlogViewModel()
        {
            Id = b.Id,
            Name = b.Name,        
            CategoryName = _context.BlogCategory
                        .Where(c => c.Id == b.CatId)
                        .Select(c => c.Name)
                        .SingleOrDefault()
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```